# Sending COA request to NAS behind NAT from Freeradius

Tags: nat, mikrotik, freeradius, aaa

My Mikrotik NAS is behind a NAT so it only has a private network IP address. So for authentication, I am using the public IP address which works fine. But when Freeradius (hosted) has to send the COA request to the Mikrotik, it fails as it does not reach using the public IP.

If I use the private IP, it is not recognised either. I am using the Mikrotiks incoming request counter to check for incoming requests but none is reaching it.

If I test using a locally deployed Freeradius, the requests are at least getting to Mikrotik. But I still need to be able to use the hosted Freeradius with the NAS behind the NAT. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

You should have configured the UDP port on The Mikrotik

Radius --> Incoming --> Port

https://erbugcelebi.medium.com/coa-change-of-authorization-from-free-radius-server-914e3ccac2e9

2. 

The Private IP is not reachable, so you have use the Public IP and a UDP forwarding in your NAT-Router to the Mirkroik

Comment: I have already done that and also ticked the accept checkbox.